# Using OpenAI API (chatgpt) in a Oracle 11g DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, openai-api, chatgpt-api

So I'm trying to use the OpenAI API to integrate in a app based in PL/SQL (Oracle 11gR2). First step I create and configure an ACL and a Wallet to access the api, and then I made a script just to test if the connection is ok. But it turns that it always returns ORA-29273: HTTP request failed.

The code of the script:

```
DECLARE
   l_url       VARCHAR2(2000) := 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions'; 
   l_request   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
   l_response  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
   l_buffer    VARCHAR2(32767);
   l_translation VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    
   UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(300);
   utl_http.set_wallet(path => 'file:PATH_OF_WALLET' ,password => 'WALLET_PW');
   
   l_request := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url => l_url, method => 'POST');
                             
   UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
   UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_request, 'Authorization', 'Bearer MY_API_KEY');
   
   l_buffer := '{"prompt": "Translate the phrase: Hello world!", "max_tokens": 50}';

   UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(l_request, l_buffer);
  
   l_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(l_request);
  
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(l_response, l_buffer, TRUE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_buffer);
      l_translation := l_buffer; 
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
      NULL; 
  END;
  
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(l_response);
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Translation: ' || l_translation);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN UTL_HTTP.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HTTP request limit exceeded.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occurred: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

The error occurs on the UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST line, I already tried with different params (https_host => 'api.openai.com' or http_version => 'HTTP/1.1' or both), and same result.

I need to use the UTL_HTTP package, because my DB doesn't have APEX installed, so the APEX_WEB_SERVICE package isn't available.

Someone with the same issue trying to use a API via HTTPS (or in specific the openAI API) in a old Oracle DB? Any tips or suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the major/minor/patch version of your Oracle database?

Comment: The version is the 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle 11.1 only supports the SSLv3 connection protocol](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl#sslv3-tlsv1-poodle); it does not support the TLS protocol. If you try to connect to a website which has disabled the SSLv3 protocol (which many websites have due to security concerns around SSLv3) then you will get the error `ORA-29273`.

To connect using:

- TLSv1, you will need to upgrade the database to at least Oracle 11.2.
- TLSv1.1 or v1.2, you will need at least Oracle version 11.2.0.4 and have applied the MES patch (found in [MOS Note 2274242.1](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=2274242.1), sign-in required)

Comment: The version i'm working is the 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: @JulioMariaAlice Is it also patched?

Comment: The DBA said that have a patch from 2019/2020 but doesn't know in specif witch one